# How to remove background-image overflow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to remove the overflow from a background-image within a div. I've got 4 divs with identical images that create one background image(I position each image so that it matches across the 4 divs). Basically I'm trying to animate the "singular" image to the left and have another image replace it within the same animation(which is really just a css transition). The problem is that the overflow: hidden hides the overflow but when you move it to the left you get to see the rest of that hidden image.

Is there any way to clip or remove the overflow so that my transition will look like one image moving to the left?

Css

```
.changeOver{
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position:130% !important;
-webkit-transition:  2s;
-moz-transition:  2s;
-o-transition:  2s;
transition:  2s;}
```

The Script

```
$('#change').click(function () {
   $('#fourth').addClass('changeOver');
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        $('#fourth').css('background-image', 'none'); 
    }, 5000);
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        $('#fourth').css('background-color', 'blue'); 
    }, 1);

    setTimeout(function(){
    $('#third').addClass('changeOver');
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        $('#third').css('background-image', 'none'); 
    }, 5000);
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        $('#third').css('background-color', 'blue'); 
    }, 1);
    }, 2000);

    setTimeout(function(){
    $('#second').addClass('changeOver');
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        $('#second').css('background-image', 'none'); 
    }, 5000);
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        $('#second').css('background-color', 'blue'); 
    }, 1);
    }, 4000);

    setTimeout(function(){
    $('#first').addClass('changeOver');
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        $('#first').css('background-image', 'none'); 
    }, 2000);
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        $('#first').css('background-color', 'blue'); 
    }, 1);
    }, 6000);    
});
```

Edit: [Here's the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/grotesqu/exksxa7q/34/) just click the button labeled 'yes'

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please be sure to read our [ask] page to help you formulate a great question.  You are much more likely to get a good answer from the community if you put some effort into your question.   ALSO, it helps if you create an  MCVE
(http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and add it to your question

Answer (score -1):

Edit: So, without redoing all your code, the problem is that you aren't moving the divs themselves.

Put {outline: 1 px solid red;} in them and you'll see that they don't actually move, which is why you're scrolling through the background. Hiding your overflow doesn't actually help unless you're moving the divs themselves, which you aren't.

You could alter the image so that whatever you want beneath it is already on it. So, the overflow is actually a different image, but they'd be the same file.

So, something like |main image|next image| all attached. That would make it look like the image is being pulled in.

If you want more of a static reveal, you would have to create four images with transparencies where the overflow would be.

It's very easy and you can even do it online with pxlr.

Otherwise, you have to animate actual divs and not just

Comment: Since that is not really an answer or solution, it belongs in the comments.

Comment: Sorry. I joined yesterday and I'm still getting the hang of doing anything more than looking at solutions.

Comment: Fair enough. For future reference.  Site makes a clear distinction between questions, answers and comments. If you have questions about someone's question or answer, it goes in the comments.  You are also free to delete an answer and move it to comments if you'd prefer.

Comment: Coolio! Appreciate the help. I edited my response to what I think would be a viable solution after they posted the fiddle rather than giving up completely.

Comment: Tnx. Up-voted your post. Glad you're mature about it. I audit first posts here on the review queue (this is a community moderated forum), and as a result see *a lot* of questions :-) Not everyone handles it as well as you. If you have time, you can try to answer questions, even submit edits to improve other's questions and increase your reputation and access to the site. At the top bar is a 'review' link where you can see the questions coming in and other queues as you climb the ranks. FYI: [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/review) and [On Topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)